# First RoR installation. Two "lib" files are not found. Is it normal?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've just installed RoR using `gem install rails`

But some files haven't been found. Please see the picture. I use Windows XP.

[image]

Also the directory `\gems\rails-3.2.12` is empty after installation. I mean this directory:

```
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rails-3.2.12
```

All other new directories under `\gems` that have been created with this installation contains something, but `\rails-3.2.12` is empty. I mean, these ones:

```
## C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems    ## the folder

builder-3.0.4
erubis-2.7.0
mime-types-1.21
polyglot-0.3.3
rails-3.2.12   ## this one is empty
railties-3.2.12
rdoc-3.9.5
... and many more
```

Is this normal? Or should I re-install it?

RoR google group is moderated. For 10 hours I couldn't get any answer. So posted a question here.

Comment: What @sevenseacat said below...

Comment: @PrakashMurthy, is this a question from you?

Comment: Nope; it was a comment approving what he said ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Perfectly normal. It occurs while installing the documentation for the gems, not the gems themselves, so you already have all the code you need. These warnings are safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

try this! It's work for me!

> gem install rdoc

and install rails again.